# How to calculate how many mines are nearby?

Tags: python, nested-lists

I am trying to add numbers to a minesweeper board.
I've followed some tutorials how to solve it. But mine is not working.
Can somebody see what's missing?

```
    field = [['.', '.', '.', '.'], 
             ['.', '.', '*', '.'], 
             ['*', '.', '*', '.'], 
             ['*', '.', '.', '*']]
    count = 0
    row = len(field)
    col = len(field[0])
    row_range = range(row - 1, row + 2)
    col_range = range(col - 1, row + 2)
    for i in row_range:
        for j in col_range:
            if 0 <= i < len(field) and 0 <= j < len(field[0]) and field[i][j] != '.':
                count += 1
                for i in range(len(field)):
                   for j in range(len(field[0])):
                       field[i][j] = count
    return field





What I need:
 [['0', '1', '1', '1'],
  ['1', '3', '*', '2'],
  ['*', '4', '*', '3'],
  ['*', '3', '2', '*']]
What I get:
[[1, 1, 1, 1], 
 [1, 1, 1, 1], 
 [1, 1, 1, 1], 
 [1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

Comment: This is not a [fully usable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it’s a bare function body. Anyone wanting to experiment with your code will have to build their own framing code to run it.

Comment: I’m afraid this code is entirely broken and needs to be rewritten from scratch. Your loop isn’t doing what you think it is. You need to loop once over cells, then for each cell, loop over the 3x3 square surrounding it. Also be sure to check your range limits; you’re using `row + 2` twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can not explain what is wrong with that code but the following is correct:

```
import copy
import pprint

field = [['.', '.', '.', '.'], 
         ['.', '.', '*', '.'], 
         ['*', '.', '*', '.'], 
         ['*', '.', '.', '*']]

output = copy.deepcopy(field)

for i in range(len(field)):
    for j in range(len(field[0])):
        if field[i][j] != '*':
            count = 0
            for a in (-1, 0, 1):
                for b in (-1, 0, 1):
                    if (0 <= i+a < len(field) and 
                        0 <= j+b < len(field[0]) and 
                        field[i+a][j+b] == '*'): 
                        count += 1
            output[i][j] = str(count)

pprint.pprint(output, width=25)
```

This prints:

```
[['0', '1', '1', '1'],
 ['1', '3', '*', '2'],
 ['*', '4', '*', '3'],
 ['*', '3', '2', '*']]
```

Comment: Yes thanks this works, but I'm wondering why would make a copy of the field?

Comment: It isn't need in this case. But I did it to make writing it easier as I could then ignore the possibility of interference as writing to the output couldn't change the input. I have written cellular automata where the output grid must be seperate from the input as the updates of each cell must be simultaneous and not sequential.